# BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ): excluded element appended as last element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to retrieve Financial Information from `reuters.com`, especially the Long Term Growth Rates of Companies. The element I want to scrape doesn't appear on all Webpages, in my example not for the Ticker `'AMCR'`. All scraped info shall be appended to a list.

I've already figured out to exclude the element if it doesn't exist, but instead of appending it to the list in a place where it should be, the `"NaN"` is appended as the last element and not in a place where it should be.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LTGRMean = []

tickers = ['MMM','AES','LLY','LOW','PWR','TSCO','YUM','ICE','FB','AAPL','AMCR','FLS','GOOGL','FB','MSFT']
```

```
   Ticker LTGRMean
0     MMM     3.70
1     AES     9.00
2     LLY    10.42
3     LOW    13.97
4     PWR    12.53
5    TSCO    11.44
6     YUM    15.08
7     ICE     8.52
8      FB    19.07
9    AAPL    12.00
10   AMCR    19.04
11    FLS    16.14
12  GOOGL    19.07
13     FB    14.80
14   MSFT      NaN
```

My individual text `"not existing"` isn't appearing.

Instead of for `AMCR` where Reuters doesn't provide any information, the Growth Rate of FLS `(19.04)` is set instead. So, as a result, all info is shifted up one index, where `NaN` should appear next to AMCR.

Comment: Please share some of your code are you using correct `range` in `for` loop.

Comment: this is all the code I'm using. The only row I left out is "print (df)".
With correct range of for loop, do you mean for loop 1 or 2?

Comment: What I meant is please provide all the code used for extracting the data from the web.

Comment: Test = requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financial-highlights/'+i)
    ReutSoup = BeautifulSoup(Test.content,'html.parser')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) Function in dataframe stacks the column to rows at level 1.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

LTGRMean = []
tickers = ['MMM', 'AES', 'LLY', 'LOW', 'PWR', 'TSCO', 'YUM', 'ICE', 'FB', 'AAPL', 'AMCR', 'FLS', 'GOOGL', 'FB', 'MSFT']

for i in tickers:
    Test = requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financial-highlights/' + i)
    ReutSoup = BeautifulSoup(Test.content, 'html.parser')
    td = ReutSoup.find('td', string="LT Growth Rate (%)")
    my_dict = {}
    #validate td object not none
    if td is not None:
        result = td.findNext('td').findNext('td').text
    else:
        result = "NaN"
    my_dict[i] = result
    LTGRMean.append(my_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(LTGRMean)
print(df.stack())
```

O/P:

```
0   MMM       3.70
1   AES       9.00
2   LLY      10.42
3   LOW      13.97
4   PWR      12.53
5   TSCO     11.44
6   YUM      15.08
7   ICE       8.52
8   FB       19.90
9   AAPL     12.00
10  AMCR       NaN
11  FLS      19.04
12  GOOGL    16.14
13  FB       19.90
14  MSFT     14.80
dtype: object
```